# Outlook shows 1600 emails for user but exchange shows 4000+ emails for user

Tags: exchange

The company I work for is not the most tech savvy and we sell castings, A user (customer service) cant get all her emails off of the server for some reason or another and the server doesnt seem to be pushing all the data to her inbox. Keep in mind I just reimaged her machine and exported the PST file before wiping it.

This is critical to her role in the company to prove that we never recieved a part they wanted to return and they never submitted a proper form for RMA. A quick response would gladly be appreciated.

Comment: You have Exchange and the user has PST file(s)? Sounds like you've got something totally backwards. How exactly did you configure the e-mail account in Outlook?

Comment: Like I said this company is not tech savvy in any way and I am an intern and cannot manage the exchange server...

Comment: Fair enough.. Question still stands; how exactly did you setup her e-mail in Outlook. Also, not to get all preachy, but they should carefully evaluate the potential losses the business could suffer from data loss, and use that when budgeting IT expenditures (like getting a consultant in there to make sure everything is running with reasonable assurance of stability and reliability).

Comment: At first run of outlook it makes you configure their account since she is on the domain, it auto fills in her account information which I double check to make sure it is correct. Once thats done I finish the setup and it starts pulling mail

Comment: Synchronization is complete? Press F9 to start/continue sync, then find "Show Progress" in the Send/Receive ribbon or one of the menus on old versions. How large is the PST file? If it's very large, try opening it (file -> open, etc).

Comment: If you can't manage the Exchange server because you're an intern, you need to punt this to the Exchange admin who can actually investigate this issue end-to-end (assuming, of course, you've done your due diligence and made sure it's not something like synchronization still being in progress on the client) ... or get those rights yourself.  I'd punt.  Less work involved.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I already have sent it in that direction and to no avail. I will try the Sync to see if that works but I believe I already tried that and again no avail

Comment: How have you established there is a difference? Can she see the 'missing' emails in outlook web access? That's a good troubleshooting step and let's her work with the data in the meantime. What version of exchange & outlook?

Comment: I already tried OWA and there was no missing ones in there. Exchange is 2007 and outlook is 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are using Exchange there should have been no need to export the email to a PST first as it would have all still been sitting on the server ready to re-download to the new computer. The only PST you would have needed to worry about would have been any Archive folders the user created because that email only exist on the workstation.

If it is Outlook 2003 or newer try disabling Cached Exchange Mode in the account settings to try and force Outlook to report what is on the server. For that matter right click on the Mailbox - Username at the top of the navigation panel in Outlook and click Properties then Folder Size to see if what Outlook sees as a mailbox size is what you are seeing in Exchange.

Also, check that there are no view filters or similiar things enabled that are hiding emails. I've seen users accidentally change a view and hide all emails older than X date or something similar.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I talked to the exchange admin and he said they dont keep anything on the server it all has to be backed up by the user (Like they know how to do that)... Any way I appreciate the thought and will try to push them to grab the backup which seems like too much of a pain for them.